# Java Macro with GUI

Tags: java

The purpose of my program is to aid me on playing Conquer Online that will auto either F1 to F10.
The problem is I am struggling on the Robot class that when I press the stop button, it won't stop the program and i can't even click that button either the "X" button from the GUI so what I had to do is to completely close my IDE(BlueJ) to exit the program.
Btw, the codes presented is not yet final I am just only struggling on it's unresponsiveness and as well as keyListeners. Sorry for the format.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Autopot extends JFrame 
{
boolean FunctionRun;
JButton Start= new JButton("Start");
JButton Stop= new JButton("Stop");

public Autopot()
{
    setTitle("Auto Pot");
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(400,230,420,300);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    JLabel Functions=new JLabel("Keys to repeat");
    Functions.setBounds(35,1,350,100);
    Functions.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.BOLD,28));
    Functions.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    getContentPane().add(Functions);

    final ArrayList<String> FKeys=new ArrayList<String>();
    FKeys.add("A");
    FKeys.add("F2");
    FKeys.add("F3");
    FKeys.add("F4");
    FKeys.add("F5");
    FKeys.add("F6");
    FKeys.add("F7");
    FKeys.add("F8");
    FKeys.add("F9");
    FKeys.add("F10");
    final String A="A";
    final JComboBox Keys= new JComboBox(FKeys.toArray());
    Keys.setBounds(55,75,150,20);
    getContentPane().add(Keys,A);


    JLabel Intervals=new JLabel("Intervals");  
    Intervals.setBounds(35,75,350,100);
    Intervals.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.BOLD,28));
    Intervals.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    getContentPane().add(Intervals);

    ArrayList<String> Interval=new ArrayList<String>();
    Interval.add("500");
    Interval.add("1000");
    Interval.add("1500");

    JComboBox KeyIntervals= new JComboBox(Interval.toArray());
    KeyIntervals.setBounds(55,150,150,20);
    getContentPane().add(KeyIntervals);



     Stop.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     Start.setBounds(75,200,120,40);
    getContentPane().add(Start);
    Start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        try{
        Start.setEnabled(false);
              Stop.setEnabled(true);  
        Robot bot=new Robot();

        FunctionRun=true;
          while(FunctionRun)
          {

              if(Keys.getSelectedItem()==A)
              {


                  bot.delay(500);
                  bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                  bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);

                }
              else
              {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Keys);
               break;
            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception Error)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Error);

    }
      }

    });

    Stop.setBounds(230,200,120,40);
    getContentPane().add(Stop);
    Stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You clicked: "+click.getSource());
            Start.setEnabled(true);
        }


});
Stop.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
{
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent stop)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Key Typed: " +stop.getKeyCode());
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent stop)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Key Released: " +stop.getKeyCode());
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent stop)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Key Pressed: " +stop.getKeyCode());
    }
});
```

}

```
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Autopot pot= new Autopot();
        pot.setVisible(true);
        pot.setResizable(false);

    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the actionPerformed method for your Stop button. What makes you thing displaying a message using JOptionPane and enabling the Start button should stop the program?

Comment: im sorry for that i was trying to get the keycode but my frame doesn't listen,  i know how to stop it by making my FunctionRun to false but please try to run my code and see what happens when you try to click the frame ans its components,  try also opening your notepad so that you can see the keyrelease and keypress methods thank you..